# Copy big files outside Java and watch the process in Java

Tags: java

A user wants to copy big files some gigabytes in java and I want to monitor the process to provide some kind of information, when the process is done.

I am monitoring the file system to check when a new file is created, modified or deleted. 
However, when a big file is transferred, I get a lot of "ENTRY_MODIFY" events - I would like to see the "ENTRY_CREATE" event (Which is done) and then I need some kind of mechanism that waits until the copy process is done.

Up to now I have a solution like this in my code for "ENTRY_CREATE":

```
            long oldSize = f.length();
            long newSize = -1;
            while(oldSize!=newSize)
            {
              oldSize= newSize;
            }
              newSize = f.length();
```

Any suggestions for this?

Thank you

Comment: Look up ProgressMonitorInputStream

Comment: OK - the copy process is initiated by some user in the system for example by pressing ctrl+c ctrl+v in that folder.
Copy is not really done by the java program

Comment: are these JVM events or OS events?

Comment: What exactly is the point of that `while` loop? An `if` statement would be more to the point. Nobody is going to magically change `newSize` while the loop is running, if that's what you're thinking.

Comment: @EJP yeah there was one statement missing, but this doesn't solve the problem

Comment: @Peterchen  For example you need one proccess bar to show you how bytes are writen , in how many time , etc and when this proccess is done your program to say "done"?

Comment: @crAlex Yep - like this, but the copy process is initiated by the OS

Comment: i think you know how to copy a simple file in java? if not let me know show i will include an answer with this and some more..

Comment: @crAlex Yes of course I now... But the file is not copied by the java program. The file is copied by an external program or by the user (CTRL+C, CTRL+X). I am able to get an event when the copy is initiated, but I don't have an idea to check when the copy is done.

Comment: so man (i thought you wanted to copy with java) ok then....